# Page get hangs and gives 'Aw, snap' error when clicking button using ('click' selenium-java and sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)) in Chrome browser

Tags: selenium

After clicking save button, page hangs and gives Aw! snap error after 2-3 minutes.

I tried below methods, but nothing worked.

```
Elements.findElement("responsive_shipping_options.gift_options_save_signed_in").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Clicks.click("responsive_shipping_options.gift_options_save_signed_in");
logger.info("Successfully clicked on change button");

Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: What did you [investigate](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fix-google-chrome-aw-snap-error/)?

Comment: When I am clicking manually, its working fine. But with code its getting hang and there is no error in logs. Script get stuck at that point and next step is not getting execute.

Comment: Add a extra sleep after sendKeys?

Comment: Tried using extra sleep but didn't work .Facing same issue.